# ASP.NET precompiled but still slow startup time?

Tags: asp.net, precompile

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong or not understanding.  I have a solution with a web application and a few class libraries.

I edited the web app publish settings of the web project. It has "precompile this application before publishing" checked and I've selected "Only files needed to run this application".

I created a publish profile which just dumps it to a folder.  From that folder I upload (using FTP) the DLLs to a staging site I have setup which is where I do final testing before deploying the app live.  After uploading the DLLs and going to the staging site there's still an app startup delay, which seems just as slow.  Isn't that supposed to be gone by precompiling?

Edit: Turning off allowing the site to be updatable fixes the problem.  Allowing it to be updateable causes all of my ASPX pages and user controls to be compiled on first page view which is causing there to still be a delay even though the code behind is compiled.  I've disabled batch compiling and turned on optimizeCompilations in the web.config and now it's fast:

```
<compilation batch="false" optimizeCompilations="true" />
```

Comment: Any chance you have `debug` setting set to true?

Comment: please define "slow". When you copy the apps over, it may trigger the application to restart.  It also depends on what the apps do (eg, load resources from DB, files, etc, etc).

Comment: It was debug in publish so I changed it to release.  I cleared out the bin directory on the server to get rid of anything not being used and re-uploaded the new DLLs.  Still slow (10+ seconds for the site to respond).

Comment: The first time or every time?  If it is just the first time, then it may not be your code.  But if it is everytime; then it could be your code; or could be your network.

Comment: Every time I upload DLLs it takes 10 or more seconds to respond. Using the site is fast, just that initial startup time is slow. If I upload the DLLs, hit the site, upload the DLLs again there's no wait.  But they aren't changed.  I think precompiling must not be working.

Comment: If I uncheck "Allow precomiled site to be uploaded" then it's fast, otherwise it's slow.  I want that checked though :(

Comment: Oh!  In that case, the Multicore JIT should be able to help you!
Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/18/an-easy-solution-for-improving-app-launch-performance.aspx

Comment: There's definitely more to this than just that web.config line. My original project which this was posted about doesn't have pre-compile selected in the publish settings and it's a very large site. No delay at all when I put new DLLs out. I have a new server now and a new site and have a long 5+ second hit every time even with that line. There must be some combination of things to get rid of the delay but I don't know yet what it is. Maybe app pool recycling delay. I'll post back when I know what all is required to get rid of the delay.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have left `debug=True` setting in config?

This will, among other things, disable batch compiling and caching (but caching should not affect your startup time).

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/04/13/575364.aspx) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx) for more details.

Comment: It was set to debug=true on the server in the web.config so I removed it.  Didn't help.  Also on my dev machine the deploy was set to debug so I changed it to release but that didn't help either.  It definitely did compile in release though.

Answer (score 0):

Which Framework version are you on?  If you are on .Net 3.5 (specifically), you should consider using:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It will approx half the cold-start time. But it is a known issue that when IIS do a cold-start on an application, there is an initial delay.  This is not limited to you deploying the application, but also when your application pool recycles.

So far, the best option that I can think of is to write a scheduled-script to automatically spin-up (warm up) a site periodically (say every 1min?).

Comment: I already actually have that in my web.config.  I'm using the site, then uploading new DLLs, then having to wait 10+ seconds for it to respond.  A script to hit the site won't help that.  This why I thought precompiling was supposed to help.  But nothings changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any solution for this. This is a known issue. There is a difference between IIS Start-up time and Compilation-time. Even if you eliminate the compilation time (by precompiling), we are still stuck with the start-up time.

Comment: It's not startup time.  If I compile everything it's nearly instant.  It's when I check "Allow precomiled site to be uploaded" then it's slow.  Has to be re-compiling everything.

Comment: Oh, in that case, the Multicore JIT will be able to help you! Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/18/an-easy-solution-for-improving-app-launch-performance.aspx

And this link will also help with Auto-Start: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure mine out. Previously my cold start was taking 18 minutes on my local dev machine (on staging it was less than 30s).

I finally noticed that a program was running high CPU during the cold restart. 
The program was.. MsMpEng.exe - This is Microsoft Security Essentials including Microsoft Defender. 
I uninstalled it and my site now loads on less than 30 seconds.

Obviously it was scanning each .dll being copied during the cold start, and blocking each additional .dll from being copied until it was finished scanning the previous one.

Cold start is now less than 30s.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the precompiled app (that was previously updated in a blink of an eye) started behaving slowly after we added SignalR.

Now, I profiled the process using [this open source tool](https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer) (disclaimer, I'm a contributor to the project, originally written by the Stackoverflow team), and I saw this among the longest call stacks:

```
//...skipped
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.AcceptCallback
//...skipped
```

<s>Thanks, Obama.</s>

<s>Wtf, Microsoft?</s>

Say hello to Owin dependency.